# How to remove parts of a str in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a variable called data and I would like to remove "//x00" from all of them if they have it. How would I go about doing so? I thought of iterating through all of them and checking each individually, but...

```
data = ["b'$VNYMR", '-103.322', '-003.191', '-018.818', '+00.0183', '+00.0107', '+00.50\\x0075', '-00.553', '+03.138', '-09.272', '+00.000038', '-00.000815', "+00.000183*6F\\x00\\r\\n'"]

for x in data:
    data[x] = data[x].replace('\\x00', '')
```

Comment: You write `data[x].replace('//x00', '')`, but items in `data` contain `\\x00`. Which is it?

Comment: `for x in data` each x is the string ... its not an index into the list

Answer (score 1):

When you call `for x in data`, x is the element in the list, not its index. You could do either

```
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = x.replace('//x00', '')
```

or

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].replace('//x00')
```

You will have to iterate through the list, as it isn't possible to do something for every element in a list without iterating through it at least once.